illegal instruction (core dumped) -error when I import TensorFlow
When I import TensorFlow in Linux terminal, I get the following error:

illegal instruction (core dumped)

I have installed TensorFlow using pip install tensorflow in Linux terminal, no errors were showing and everything has been installed successfully. I also tried installing it from GitHub yet that issue persists. I am on Ubuntu-20.04 virtual machine and Python3 is installed on it.
What can I do to solve it?
